# How to scan an image straight onto a cloud database through web browser interface

Tags: database, image, upload, cloud

I have a MySQL cloud database with a browser-based front-end.

Backend code is written using Perl/Dancer

The employee logs on to www.example.com and enters the data into fields, hits ' save ' to create a new record.

Now I need to scan in an image and attach it as one of the fields.

How can I accomplish this?

I realise that I could just scan the image, save it as a file on the desktop, and then upload this file. but there is a high volume of data to process, this method is very clunky.

( It isn't essential that it is a scanner, it could equally well be a web cam or digital camera )

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "mysql cloud database"?  Are you wanting the web browser to control a scanner, our will the user do this manually? Are you thinking the image will go from the browser to the database without being submitted to the back end web server? Storing images inside a relational database may not be the best design choice; are alternative options possible?

Comment: Can I control the scanner from a browser?  I should have just asked that question first probably!

Comment: Basically I just need to get a scan into the database, and I'm trying to figure out my possible solution paths.

Answer (score -1):

To control scanner's from browser u may either use activeX controls  or u may use flash, which gives options to take options from web/digital